# Python Concatenate strings stored in one variable into a single list

Tags: python, list

so i have this variable which has stored multiple strings:

```
123
456
789
876
543
```

each string inside the variable is also classified as a string:

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
```

however when i try to get them all into a single list with attemps like:

```
for x in varwithstr:
    full_lst = []
    full_lst.append(x)
```

or

```
    l = x.split(" ")
```

i do not get the desired result:

```
['123','456','789','876','543']
```

instead i either get :

```
['123']
['456']
['789']
['876']
['543']
```

or:

```
['1']
['2']
['3']
['5']
['6']
['7']
['8']
['9']
['8']
['7']
['6']
['5']
['4']
['3']
```

does anyone know what i'm missing here?

Full Code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os

path = 'data/path'


for filenames in os.listdir(path):
    if filenames.endswith('.xml'):
        fullnames = os.path.join(path, filenames)
        tree = ET.parse(fullnames)
        root = tree.getroot()
        IDs = root[2].attrib.get("ProjectID")
```

IDs is the variable i'm refering to.

`print(type(IDs))`gives back the following `<class 'str'>`

Comment: `full_lst = []` should NOT be in the loop, as is you create a new list every iteration - move it to before the loop

Comment: Your depiction of `varwithstr` at the beginning of your question is not very informative - that just looks like data, not a python object. Please read [mre].

Comment: if you scroll down all the way, you can find the full code and also explanation for the `varwithstr`example

Answer (score 0):

The lines are separated by '\n' (newline) and not ' ' (space). So maybe this can work.

```
l = x.split("\n")
```